# Unable to use Pytorch with CUDA in Celery task

Tags: pytorch, celery

I have a celery task that uses torch library, which internally uses CUDA. When I run the task, it fails saying
"Cannot re-initialize CUDA in forked subprocess. To use CUDA with multiprocessing, you must use the 'spawn' start method"

When I browsed on this a little, I got this - https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/6036
This issue says Celery supports only fork and not spawn.

Is there any workaround/alternative to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may start celery worker with "solo" pool type

`celery -A tasks worker --pool=solo --loglevel=info`

Solo creates only one thread and runs celery tasks using that thread. Concurrency number cannot be provided here.

Answer (score 3):

you should load pytorch model and use it as global variable. The instance of model and task will run in the same process

```
from celery.signals import worker_process_init
# for more information about worker_process_init, read here:
# https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/signals.html#worker-process-init

pytorch_model = None

@worker_process_init.connect()
def init_worker_process(**kwargs):
    """
    load model before running tasks
    :param kwargs:
    :return:
    """
    global pytorch_model
    pytorch_model = load_model()

@app.task
def predict_task(image: np.ndarray):
    return pytorch_model.predict(image)
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread, but leaving this here in case anyone encounters the same problem. setting `--pool=solo` solves the cuda error, but it makes celery's `control.inspect()` return None. To avoid, use `celery -A tasks worker --pool=threads`. This solved the cuda error for me, while `control.inspect()` stays available.

Other solutions like setting `torch.multiprocessing('spawn', force=True)` did nothing for me.

(The first answer was not an option, as the cuda error was only popping up when Transformer's `TrainingArguments()` was called. Loading the model as a global or after `TrainingArguments()` was called didn't solve anything.)

(Using torch & transformers in a FastAPI+Celery+Redis+Flower environment)